# htaccess again - special url rewrite to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I hope someone would help me, because I'm stuck with this:

domain name - test.site.com
document root == /www/test
all content (CMS) located at /www/test/web
I need when I type in addressbar: 
1) test.site.com/* - site opens from /www/test/web and addressbar keeps URL "test.site.com/*"

2) type test.site.com/web/* - the same behavior - site opens from web and URL changed to "test.site.com/*"

3) an exception - type test.site.com/folder1 - opens page from /www/test/folder1

I can redirect to "web" subfolder In such a way:

.htacesss in /www/test:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.site.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

but it works only for 1) requirement.
2) and 3) doesn't work.
and as for 3) I can see that *every* request will be redirected to "web" subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd requirement you need an additional rule to redirect /web to /root.

Something like this :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /web/([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
```

The rule above will match any request starting with /web/foo and redirect the request to /foo.

And for the 3rd, you need a RewriteCond to exclude the /folder1 from RewriteRule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1
```

REWRITE

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /web/([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1        RewriteRule ((?!web).*) /web/$1 [NC,L]
```